# Java list in JSON notation

Tags: java, json

for example I have a `List<Point> vertices` which has 3 points and each of them have x and y would look in JSON notation?

for example List vertices:

```
[0] -> x = 1 , y = 2
[1] -> x = 4, y = 5
[2] -> x = 7, y = 5
```

Considering that object Color has two parameters and in JSON it looks like

```
"colour":{"value":-16711936,"falpha":0.0}...
```

So it should look like

```
"[0]":{"x": 1, "y":2}...
```

And so on. But i need to put it in the List **vertices** in JSON.

Comment: I dont get it, you want to serialize a Map of points, Colors??

Comment: {"listOfShapeEvents":[{"xStart":20,"yStart":40,"xEnd":30,"yEnd":90,"colour":{"value":-65536,"falpha":0.0},"thickness":5,"shapeType":"LINE","eventType":"SHAPE"}]} I have this this is my straight Line, which reading just an objects from Java. But i need to read a list named "vertices" which has 3 points and each point has 2 parameters x and y . How is going to look in JSON notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON for your described array of points would like this:

```
[
  {
    "x" : 1,
    "y" : 2
  },
  {
    "x" : 4,
    "y" : 5
  },
  {
    "x" : 7,
    "y" : 5
  }
]
```

Note the use of square brackets to indicate this is an array.

Answer (score 2):

This conversion problem has been solved with multiple java libraries. Jackson is a good library for Java to / from JSON

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: SO answers are not for recommending libraries.